# Order HashMap<String,Integer> according Integer

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Dear,
i have an hash map, in which i have saved tho values: singer(string) and popularity(integer).

Now, i want order this hash map according the popularity.

How can do it in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you store the singer as a key, and the popularity (of the singer) as value. A HashMap is not ordered, and a TreeMap is ordered by key, not by value, so it won't help.

If you need your singers ordered by popularity, then build a list with all the singers in the map, and then sort this list using a comparator which compares the popularity of both singers:

```
List<String> singers = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(singers, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        Integer popularity1 = map.get(s1);
        Integer popularity2 = map.get(s2);
        return popularity1.compareTo(popularity2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

HashMaps can (by design) not be ordered. If you need an ordered map, use the [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: `TreeMap` wouldn't help you to sort a map by value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the order of HashMap elements. Make a new `TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>` and copy your data to it. Use `List<String>` to cover the cases where you have duplicate int values.